# Oracle Express 11g No message file for product=NETWORK

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-xe

I have installed Oracle Express 11g on my windows 8 desktop. Prior to installing I checked ORACLE_HOME was not set. After installing it still wasn't. So I created it:

```
ORACLE_HOME=E:\DATA\Dev\Oracle11gXE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
```

I have not touched any other file.

When I check the services OracleServiceXE is running but OracleXETNSListener refuses to start. I need it for sql developer, etc.

Don't know if it's related but when I try and open 'get started' icon which goes to: http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950 I just get a page not found and port 8080 is fine to open (as I run tomcat) despite tomcat, etc not running.

When I check the log.xml all I see is about 10 repeating items like this:

```
<msg time='2015-07-07T18:52:01.076+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='NCOMPUTER'
     host_addr='fe80::10e2:c588:6413:cf%3' version='1'>
 <txt>Message 279 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL
 </txt>
</msg>
```

I tried changing the listener file to use localhost but get the same error, as do with tnsnames.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = E:\DATA\Dev\Oracle11gXE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = E:\DATA\Dev\Oracle11gXE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

and

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was the wrong oracle_home set.

The default home should be something like this:
`C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. It looks like someone had a similar problem and there are 3 things you need to check.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2322893?tstart=0

Comment: thanks, but ORACLE_HOME as per my first line is set, I've also tried it not set. Language is fine, and this is brand new install so nothing in mesg.

Windows registry has an entry under oracle\key_xe that all looks fine and sets ORACLE_HOME so probably not needed anyway. Additionally there is an ORACLE_HOME in registry under KEY_OracleHome, but that is for weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar error but am not sure whether it is the same as yours.

However if your computer gets is a DHCP then you need to install a

Loopbackadapter
here is a very simple guide to installing it.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14316/reqs.htm

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, so your problem is likely already solved.

There is another environment variable:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

which must be set to:

```
%ORACLE_HOME%\lib
```

(%ORACLE_HOME% of course being the base of your database installation (ie `c:\oracle\product\12.1.2\db_home1`)